# How to disable precision of categorical column values after merging dataframes?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge, categories

I have 4 dataframes with one categorical column.

```py
d1:
ID  d1c
002 [0, 25)
004 [25, 50)

d2:
ID  d2c
002 [0, 25)
005 [0, 25)

d3:
ID  d3c
004 [25, 50)
005 [0, 25)

ID  d4c
002 [25, 50)
004 [75, 100)

d1['d1c'].value_counts()
[25, 50)     1
[0, 25)      1
Name: d1c, dtype: int64

d1.dtypes
ID         object  
d1c    category
dtype: object
```

I have to merge dataframes by outer join. So I merged these dataframes as follows:

```py
ds=[d1,d2,d3,d4]
ds_final=reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on='ID',how='outer'),ds)
```

But the result generates the desired result, BUT the categorical columns show different format, it shows float type instead of integer.

```py
ID  d1c            d2c           d3c            d4c
002 [0.0, 25.0)    [0.0, 25.0)   NaN            [25.0, 50.0)
004 [25.0, 50.0)   NaN           [25.0, 50.0)   [75.0, 100.0)
005 NaN            [0.0, 25.0)   [0.0, 25.0)    NaN
```

But when I count the unique values of a column, it shows the datatype as int64 and categorical values are shown without precision.

```py
ds_f['d1c'].value_counts()
[25, 50)     1
[0, 25)      1
[75, 100)    0
Name: d1c, dtype: int64

ds_f.dtypes
ID     object  
d1c    category
d2c    category
d3c    category
d4c    category
dtype: object
```

Why the format in display was changed after merging dataframes? I want in [0, 25) format.

Comment: I suspect this has to do with the appearance of NaN is in your combined dataframe.  pandas has a side effect of changing the dtype of a column to float if NaNs are present.

Comment: You could convert those pd.Interval to strings and keep the format you want.

Comment: @ScottBoston is right. Its related to NaN values. I use extra style Pandas.io.formats.style.Styler(df,precision=None), then worked!